# Expanding div not pushing down content in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I am using the plugin linked below as a portfolio. You click a thumbnail and it expands a div to reveal content, which pushes down any thumbnails below it. This works fine in modern browser, but I have to support IE8. The plugin claimed to support it, but in IE8, the bottom rows of thumbnails are not being pushed down.

http://plugins.gravitysign.com/colio/index_black.html

I suspect it has something to do with position:absolute. To push the bottom thumbnails down, the script is dynamically changing the top:xxx position on each li based on the height of the expanded div. But this position is not being properly changed or not being honored in IE8.

Here is the source code for the colio plugin: http://plugins.gravitysign.com/colio/js/jquery.colio.js

This appears to be the relevant section from the jquery.colio.js code (I think?):

```
     // variables           
    var duration = this.settings.expandDuration, 
        easing = this.settings.expandEasing;

    // get content_id for item to get viewport height to make a gap in item grid
    var content_id = item.data('colio-content-id');
    var viewport_height = this.getViewportHeight(content_id);

    // add any bottom margins to colio viewport height
    viewport_height += parseFloat(this.markup.css('margin-bottom'));

// push items that are below colio viewport down by the amount of viewport height
        $.each(this.insideBottomItems(item), function(){

            // save initial top position
            var item_top = $(this).data('colio-item-top');
            if(item_top === undefined) {
                item_top = parseFloat($(this).css('top')) || 0;
                $(this).data('colio-item-top', item_top);
            }

            // add class to items that we have pushed down
            $(this).addClass('colio-bottom-item');

            // push items using animation
            $(this).stop().animate({top: item_top + viewport_height}, duration, easing);

        });
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: We can't help without being able to see the code you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I'm referring to the demo I linked to above. I will link directly to the source code and edit my post. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: In a Windows 7 virtual machine, with IE10 running the IE8 rendering mode, I don't see any issues: http://d.pr/i/tzUy

Comment: When you click on "View Project" in any thumbnail on the first row, do you see the second row get pushed down? In my Windows 7 IE8 testing, that second row never pushes down to make room for the expanded div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who tried to help so far. Though I wasn't able to solve the actual problem, I was able to fix it well enough with a simple edit. I just made the z-index higher on the expanded content div so that it overlaps the thumbnails that it failed to push down. I suppose this counts as a "good enough" solution, but I'll leave it open in case anyone else knows how to force IE8 to push down those bottom rows.

Answer (score 0):

Can't quite well test this but what about adding an empty DIV that mimicks the position:absolute one, but with regular positioning?
Add an onresize function that will set "shadowDiv" 's size to the same proportions to the  "floatingDIV"?

```
...
<div id="shadow">
<div style="position:absolute;" id="float"></div>
</div>
...
document.getElementById('float').onresize = function(){
 var shadow = document.getElementById('shadow');
 shadow.style.width = this.style.width;
 shadow.style.height = this.style.height;
}
...
```

Comment: That's an interesting thought. Where would I put the <div id="shadow"> since the absolutely position div is created dynamically and is not actually in the HTML to start with?

Comment: In that case, maybe try something like floatDiv.outerHTML = '<div id="shadow">'+floatDiv.outerHTML+'</div>'. Or just redirect the creation of the div to the shadowDiv which would have to be there before the creation. Depends on what would suit your problem best.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `ul` containing all of the thumbnails is given a fixed `height: 440px` and when the "view project" div is created/expanded, it's given `position: absolute` with page offsets.

Even in modern browsers, this wouldn't push elements down so I imagine there's some javascript fail for IE8. You can solve this a few ways:

- Add some extra code to manually adjust the position of the lower thumbnails.
- Use z-index to ensure the opened div is always covering the thumbnails
- Open the absolutely positioned content lower or as some form of modal dialog
- Try to route out the difference between IE8 and the browsers this works in

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do the modal dialog option that will still push the content down? I need that part of the functionality as opposed to overlaying the content. Manually adding code may be tough since the number of rows and the thumbnails in each row will always change, since the site is responsive.

Comment: Modal dialog means it's covering all content, like a new window. So that's not what you'd like. I'd just throw some manual javascript in there to manually push down the lower `li` elements. It's ugly, but then again it's IE we're dealing with

Comment: Is there a way to manually do it when I don't know what the height of the expanded div will be? It changes with the content that's inside it, so I'm not sure how to manually position them. The li's that end up below the expanded content are given a class of "colio-bottom-item". So I could try to target those. This is the line that currently sets the new top position for the bottom items, but appears to fail in IE8: $(this).stop().animate({top: item_top + viewport_height}, duration, easing);

Comment: Using jquery you can determine the `top` and `height` of the project content div, add the two together plus some "spacing" and then use that value as the new `top` for the lower `li`s

Comment: Thank you. Though isn't that what "top: item_top + viewport_height" is already doing, though unsuccessfully in IE8?

Comment: Possibly. You can try to spend time debugging those values in IE8 and see what might be causing the calculations to be off.

Comment: I edited my code to include the math they're using for viewport_height. Unfortunately I can't see errors in the firebug lite console for IE8, so I'm not seeing any issues. Is jQuery animate supposed to work in IE8?

Comment: Generally it should but there's a ton of results for problems with it in IE8